# How to set depth to 1 in Neo4j Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

How can I set the depth/limit the number of hops in Spring Data?

I'm using Neo4j DB with SDN, and since I have a cycle I keep getting an infinite loop.

I'm trying to retrieve all my nodes with the related relationships and target nodes with a depth of 1 (only one hop) with the following query:

MATCH p = (u1:User)-[r]->(u2:User) WITH *, relationships(p) AS r RETURN u1, collect(r), collect(u2)

My model is as follow:

```
@Node
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Property
private String name;

@Relationship(type="RELATED")
private List<Relationship> relationship;

//constructor, getter and setters 

}
```

```
@RelationshipProperties
public class Relationship{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Property
private String role;

@TargetNode
private User user;

//constructor, getter and setters 

}
```

I understood that to set the depth to 1 I should add *1 to the relation as below:

MATCH (u1:User})-[r*1]->(u2:User) RETURN u1, collect(r), collect(u2)

Neo4J flag that solution (adding *n) as deprecated an I should operate with a path, so I wrote the following query:

MATCH p = (u1:User)-[r]->(u2:User) WITH *, relationships(p) AS r RETURN u1, collect(r), collect(u2)

The previous query seems to work as intended if I try to execute it in Neo4J Browser but if executed in Spring Data I get an infinite loop

This is the query in my repository

```
@Query("MATCH p = (u1:User)-[r]->(u2:User) WITH *, relationships(p) AS r RETURN u1, collect(r), collect(u2)")
Collection<User> getAllUser();
```

This are the dependencies I'm working with:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.28</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Side note: your setup is incorrect. Spring Data Neo4j starter 2.6 will bring Spring Data Neo4j 6. Your Neo4j OGM Bolt driver dependency is for Spring Data Neo4j 5 and will not be used.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption regarding the query is wrong.

> I understood that to set the depth to 1 I should add *1 to the relation as below:
> `MATCH (u1:User})-[r*1]->(u2:User) RETURN u1, collect(r), collect(u2)`

For `MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)` the `r` is exactly one relationship (like your query with `*1`. Downside of this query style is that every `n` (in your case the `User`) has to fulfill this pattern. If there is a `User` without a relationship, it won't get returned.

Because start and end of your relationship have the same label (`User`), you could use `MATCH p = (u1:User)-[*0..1]->(:User) RETURN u1, collect(relationships(p)), collect(nodes(p))`

Another approach, if you have multiple use cases demanding this reduced view, is to use projection:

```
interface UserWithDepthOne { // *
    String getName();

    List<RelationshipProjection> getRelationship();

    interface RelationshipProjection {
        String getRoles();

        UserWithoutRelationship getUser();

        interface UserWithoutRelationship {

            String getName();
        }
    }
}
```

(*The projections don't have to be nested, here just for the overview)

And in your repository:

```
Collection<UserWithDepthOne> getAllUser();
```

More on projections can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.sdn.multi-level).